# Draw pixel in C

Tags: c, opengl

I'm trying to draw triangle in C using opengl but without standard opengl functions for drawing triangles and lines. (I use ubuntu.)

I used Bresenham line drawing algoritm. I suppose, that the code of this algorithm itself is fine, because it draws tringle but it look like on following picture. 
[image]

And I need to make it look like this

[image]

In the line drawing algorithm I draw the line pixel by pixel using following function:

```
void setPixel(int x, int y) {
    glBegin(GL_POINTS);
    glVertex2i(x,y);
    glEnd();
    glFlush();
}
```

Could you help me with the following? :
Why aren't the lines smooth? 
Why is there a space between pixels? 
Why aren't the lines thinner?

Comment: What size have you set your pixels? Are you using any form of Anti Aliasing?

Comment: @rhughes - Bresenhams doesn't have anti-aliasing. You could run it at a higher resolution then downsample, but it'd probably be better to use a line-drawing algorithm that has anti-aliasing built in. In this case, though, the "wanted" illustration doesn't seem to be anti-aliased either (there's staircasing on the RHS), so maybe by "why aren't the lines smooth?" OP is just referring to the huge "pixels".

Comment: It is worth noting to, that as this is in 3D space, you don't really have 'pixels' in the sense of a 2D image. If you are looking for more control over pixels exactly, try either rendering to an image or looking into a 2D API.

Comment: As @Steve314 said, I meant that huge pixels. I should have been more specific.Actually, I can't use 2D API,so I'm going to try rendering. Thank you all.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to change point size with

```
glPointSize(1.0f); // or similar value
```

before `glBegin` call.

Answer (score 1):

- As stated by @Nemanja Boric, points aren't simple pixels.
  One does usually draw such squares using `glBegin(GL_QUADS)`, since the point size is limited.
- If this is not a line drawing exercise, use `glBegin(GL_LINE_LOOP);`

  - `glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);` for smooth lines
  - [`glLineWidth();`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glLineWidth.xml) to adjust the line width. However, with `GL_LINE_SMOOTH` enabled, the line looks thinner because of antialiasing.

Comment: Actually it is a line drawing exercise. I tried what @NemanjaBoric suggested, but it just made the square smaller and so the black spaces in between are bigger.

Comment: Pixel perfect drawing in OpenGL is rather tricky. If performance is not important at all, you may try with `glDrawPixels()`: http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glDrawPixels.xml . You could draw each pixel separately, which would get horribly slow, or draw a bitmap (offscreen) in native C and draw it using one call to that function.

Comment: Thanks @Sam I'm going to try that.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not use point primitives to represent pixels. If you have anti-aliasing enabled (`GL_MULTISAMPLE` or the older `GL_POINT_SMOOTH`), then they are not actually rectangular in nature.

Since you are using an older version of OpenGL here, you still have direct access to raster functions. That is, you can skip primitive assembly and draw relative to `glRasterPos2i (...)`. `glWindowPos2i (...)` will even skip coordinate transform and let you draw directly in window coordinates without messing with projection/modelview matrices (assuming you have an OpenGL 1.4+ implementation).

#### Here is how you could accomplish the same thing as in your sample code:

```
void setPixel(int x, int y) {
  const GLubyte color [] = { 255, 255, 255, 255 };

  glWindowPos2i (x, y);
  glDrawPixels  (1, 1, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, color);

  glFlush();
}
```

If you don't have access to `glWindowPos2i`, then use an orthographic projection matrix equal to your window's dimensions and an identity modelview matrix and replace `glWindowPos2i (...)` with `glRasterPos2i (...)`.

Neither solution will be high-performance, but at least you will not have to worry about things like point size, depth tests, etc.

Comment: Thanks for advice. I tried it, but I got "segmentation fault (core dumped)" probably caused by  glWindowPos2i (x, y). But when I put it in comment, I receive no error. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @quida: Like I said, if `glWindowPos2i` is not supported, then use an orthographic projection matrix with the same dimensions as your window and identity modelview matrix. If you do this, then `glRasterPos2i` will behave the same as `glWindowPos2i`. I believe you already have your application setup this way if `glVertex2i` was drawing points in window coordinates.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realised, you wrote it there before. I will try it that way. Thanks a lot.